# App Inventor 2 Activity Starter

Tags: android, bluetooth, app-inventor

I'm making an android app and I want to know if is there any way to:

1. Reject/Answer the incomming call ( I just need a function line. Something like this example "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE" but of course I don't mean bluetooth. )
2. Get the text of incommig SMS and store it in text variable.

I'm almost sure the first point is doable by activity starter but I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the `Activity Starter`.

Please take a look at the documentation about the [PhoneCall](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#PhoneCall) component and the [Texting](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#Texting) component.

For the `PhoneCall` component there are the following events available:

> **IncomingCallAnswered(text phoneNumber)**
>       Event indicating that an incoming phone call is answered. phoneNumber is the incoming call phone number. 
> **PhoneCallEnded(number
>   status, text phoneNumber)**
>       Event indicating that a phone call has ended. If status is 1, incoming call is missed or rejected; if status is 2, incoming call is
>   answered before hanging up; if status is 3, outgoing call is hung up.
>   phoneNumber is the ended call phone number.
> **PhoneCallStarted(number
>   status, text phoneNumber)**
>       Event indicating that a phonecall has started. If status is 1, incoming call is ringing; if status is 2, outgoing call is dialled.
>   phoneNumber is the incoming/outgoing phone number.

1. to reject/answer an incoming call is not possible with App Inventor.
2. to get the text of an incoming SMS is easily doable, but your App Inventor app must be up and running. Just use the `MessageReceived` event, see also the [No Text While Driving](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/no-text-while-driving-ai2) tutorial.

**First do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the  [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)**

Comment: That is not good.
So my last chance to reject/answer incoming calls is to jump from C++ to java and make my own application. Am I right ?

Comment: A huge hole in AI usability btw

Comment: @TimHallman in case it is possible in Android, just write your own extension... see also the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html) about how to write an App Inventor Extension.